# Keyboard show only number

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard, ios-simulator

I can not enter any letters and symbol.There are only numbers on keyboard when simulator is running.How can i change this to be normal keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard types are as follows

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIKeyboardType) {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
#if __IPHONE_4_1 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad with a decimal point.
#endif
#if __IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
#endif

};
```

So just change your textfield keyboard to one of the above like this

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```